# Android WebView Shows Old URL

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have a webView and 3 buttons that shows 3 different urls. If I press the first button that shows url_1, when I press the back button and I finish with it, and come back to the activity, everything is fine. But when I press the second button to show url_2, url_1 briefly appears, and then url_2 appears. When I press the back button it goes from url_2 to url_1 and then back to the activity. This issue happens no matter what order I press the buttons in, meaning if I press the third button for url_3, it (url_1) will always briefly appear first whenever I press the other 2 buttons, before their urls show.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding.button1.setOnClickListener {
        loadWebViewWith("first_url")
    }

    binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
        loadWebViewWith("second_url")
    }

    binding.button3.setOnClickListener {
        loadWebViewWith("third_url")
    }
}

fun loadWebViewWith(urlStr: String) {

    binding.webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE // shows the webView in the current activity

    binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    binding.webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    binding.webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true

    clearWebViewCache()
    
    binding.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest? ): Boolean {
            request?.url?.let {
                view?.loadUrl(it.toString())
            }
            return true
        }

        @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            url?.let {
                view?.loadUrl(it)
            }
            return true
        }
    }

    binding.webView.loadUrl(urlStr)
}

override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    if (event.getAction() === KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> {
                if (binding.webView.canGoBack()) {
                    binding.webView.goBack()
                } else {

                    binding.webView.visibility = View.GONE // hides the webView in the current activity
                    clearWebViewCache()
                }
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}

fun clearWebViewCache() { // I tried these in different combinations

    binding.webView.clearCache(true)
    binding.webView.clearFormData()
    binding.webView.clearHistory()
    binding.webView.clearSslPreferences()

    binding.webView.loadUrl("about:blank")
    binding.webView.reload()

    binding.webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE

    WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData()

    CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null)
    CookieManager.getInstance().flush()

    this.deleteDatabase("webview.db")
    this.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the webView.clearHistory() inside onPageFinished method of the webViewClient.

Create a boolean variable at the top level.

```
    lateinit var button1 : Button
    lateinit var button2 : Button
    lateinit var button3 : Button
    lateinit var webView: WebView
    var canClear : Boolean = false
```

Set it to true after loading a url.

```
        button1.setOnClickListener {
            loadWebViewWith("url")
            canClear = true
        }

        button2.setOnClickListener {
            loadWebViewWith("url")
            canClear = true
        }

        button3.setOnClickListener {
            loadWebViewWith("url")
            canClear = true
        }
```

override the onPageFinished function

```
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                if(canClear){
                    canClear = false
                    view?.clearHistory()
                }

            }
```

Comment: Hi! I tried it, it didn't work. The problem still occurred.